# Azure Search; Search inside a specific field

Tags: c#, .net, search, azure-cognitive-search

In Azure Search can i do searching on specific field(s)

Example: I have the below "Research" Index.

```
{
  "Error": null,
  "IsSuccess": true,
  "StatusCode": 201,
  "Body": {
    "name": "Research",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "Id",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": false,
        "filterable": false,
        "sortable": false,
        "facetable": false,
        "suggestions": false,
        "key": true,
        "retrievable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Title",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": true,
        "filterable": false,
        "sortable": false,
        "facetable": false,
        "suggestions": true,
        "key": false,
        "retrievable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Description",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": true,
        "filterable": false,
        "sortable": false,
        "facetable": false,
        "suggestions": true,
        "key": false,
        "retrievable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Questions",
        "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
        "searchable": true,
        "filterable": false,
        "sortable": false,
        "facetable": false,
        "suggestions": true,
        "key": false,
        "retrievable": true
      },
    ],
    "scoringProfiles": [],
    "defaultScoringProfile": null,
    "corsOptions": null
  }
}
```

Now in the search query can I ask Azure to search only in the "Questions" field?

E.g. When user search for "How Internet of things benefits automotive industry?" and selects i want to find this in only "Questions" would i able to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using the `searchFields=[string]` parameter.  For example, in your case you would add `&searchFields=Questions` to your URL search request.  You can learn more about this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798927.aspx