# Azure Search - query within a specific field using the .Net SDK

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

We are attempting to build our API for our Azure Search index using the .Net SDK for Azure Search.  We are trying to write the equivalent code for the `searchFields` parameter of the query found in the Rest API syntax for Azure Search (found via this thread: [Azure Search; Search inside a specific field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441033/azure-search-search-inside-a-specific-field))

After lengthy research, there doesn't seem to be any such equivalent to use in the .Net SDK when we want to query on a specific field of our Azure Search index.  Could this possibly be the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.searchparameters.searchfields#Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_SearchParameters_SearchFields).

Comment: Bruce, you're always a great help.  Thanks.